# Can you use jsp for your front end while your backend routes are restful in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
@RestController
```

public class IndexController {

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String indexRoute() {
    return JSON HERE;
}
```

Suppose the above is my backend route, is there any way with jsp in which i can display that?
I really dont want to use React to embed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```java
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public MyResource idexJson() {
        ...
        return res;
    }

    @GetMapping("/jsp")
    public String input(final Model model) {
        ...
        model.addAttribute(res);
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Additionally, you may possibly need additional configuration. For example:

properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
```

dependencies:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

---

[Example code](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/en62542331)

Comment: Yes i got that, but how is res available inside /jsp?

Comment: Wouldn't [that sample code](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/blob/e0ecd9ab580a6dff40bb112c0b2cae3588c06b2f/en62542331/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp#L9) be helpful?/ reference: [1.3.4. Model](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods)

Comment: See ya in the Github link that you send, the /jsp is calling the createResource(), that is how it is getting the res data. It is not calling the /json route to get the json data. I want that to happen

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can annotate your class with `@RestController` to tell Spring that it's methods will return a HTTP response body (in JSON format for example)

And you can annotate an other class with `@Controller` to tell Spring that it's methods will return a view name (like a JSP file name for example)

Comment: How will i call the Rest apis to display the data in my jsps?

Comment: your Controller's method will have to call RestController's method and put the result in org.springframework.ui.Model using it's addAttribute method. Notice that is a very weird design

Comment: How will i call the restController method from inside my Controller method?